# simple way to transfer data from java class to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, web

I have a string `String myString = "This is some text."` I also have a getter `getMyString()`
I have a jsp page I want to bring it to and then store it in localStorage. since this isn't exactly my expertise I've tried doing it like...

```
var myJSString = "<%=myString%>";
var myJSString = <%  getMyString(); %>
```

they both give me the same error

> HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

```
root cause 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
```

I've looked through numerous tutorials and I haven't been able to get this to work. What other ways are there to put a java variable into a javascript variable?

Comment: `getAccountName()` method should be called on an object, where did you immplement that method..

Comment: Where is defined the Java variable `myString` or method `getMyString()`?

Comment: @Paul Vargas in a separate java class file that isn't in the jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't use [Expression Language](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/essential-jsp-expression) or [JSTL](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/how_to_use_jstl_tag_in_jsp_page.html)? e.g.

#### Expression Language

```
var myJSString = "${myString}";
```

#### JSTL

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
...

var myJSString = '<c:out value="${myString}"/>';
```

Comment: you know what. that sounds good. I might end up using one of these 2 ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cant really access the variables created by JSP in javascript. What I used to do is , create a hidden element and assign the value to it via scriptlet. Once the page loads , access the hidden element's value via javascript.

```
<input type="hidden" id="accountName" value='<%= bean.getAccountName(); %>'/>
```

Now when the page is rendered you will get something like this.

```
<input type="hidden" id="accountName" value='Myaccountname'/>
```

You can access this value with javascript using `document.getelementByID("accountName");`

Note:

1.getAccountName() should be called from a bean

2.I havent checked the syntax of the code above.Just typed it fast , but this method will get your job done.